# Create YAML file in terminal - MacOS

Tags: macos, terminal, conda, zsh

Either I'm too stupid or I can't find the right command.

How can I create a simple YAML file using the ZSH terminal?

Comment: Have you tried these commands?  `echo "basic" > basic.yml`  or  `touch simple.yml`

Comment: There is no special YAML type of file. If the contents of an ordinary text file can be parsed as YAML, it's a YAML file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create `yml` file like these commands

`echo "basic" > basic.yml` or `touch simple.yml`

Answer (score 5):

YAML is just a format so you can create any text file and just add an .yml or .yaml extension.

Command for creating files in zsh is ***touch***

```
touch test.yaml
```

What people usually do is to just open a terminal text editor like **nano** or **vim** add the content and save as *.yml or *.yaml

Answer (score 0):

First you should create a conda environment in the **folder** you want to have like this (I call the environment "project_name"):

```
conda create -n project_name python=3.9
```

After that you should activate your environment in the terminal like this:

```
conda activate project_name
```

Finally, you could use this command to export a yaml file. I call it "environment.yaml" like this:

```
conda env export > environment.yaml
```

Then you can go to your folder in finder and check the file. The output may look like this:

```
name: project_name
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - ca-certificates=2023.01.10=hecd8cb5_0
  - libcxx=14.0.6=h9765a3e_0
  - libffi=3.4.4=hecd8cb5_0
  - ncurses=6.4=hcec6c5f_0
  - openssl=1.1.1t=hca72f7f_0
  - pip=23.0.1=py39hecd8cb5_0
  - python=3.9.16=h218abb5_2
  - readline=8.2=hca72f7f_0
  - setuptools=66.0.0=py39hecd8cb5_0
  - sqlite=3.41.2=h6c40b1e_0
  - tk=8.6.12=h5d9f67b_0
  - tzdata=2023c=h04d1e81_0
  - wheel=0.38.4=py39hecd8cb5_0
  - xz=5.4.2=h6c40b1e_0
  - zlib=1.2.13=h4dc903c_0
prefix: /Users/quinten/opt/miniconda3/envs/project_name
```